# checking duplicate characher in a string

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

In an interview i was asked to check weather a given string has duplicate characters. Googleing about this question i came to know about a question which uses bit-manipulation.

```
bool check(char*name)
{
     int i;
     int checker=0;
     for(i=0;name[i]!=0;i++)
     {
        int val=name[i]-'a';
        if((checker&(1<<val))>0)return false;
          checker|=(1<<val);
     }
     return true;
 }
```

I check this code and It is working fine.But I didn't understand the logic behind this line.

```
> if((checker&(1<<val))>0)return false;
>               checker|=(1<<val);
```

And second doubt is that will this work if a string is too long or contains Unicode(2 byte wide chars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm uses 1 bit per ascii character to indicate existence to the set. So it at least works for English lowercase letters -- 26 of them and with successive ascii codes.
a= 000001, b= 000010, c= 000100, etc.
'aacaaccc' and 'ac' and 'ca' would all encode to 000101 regardless of the number of occurances of a and c. Thus the string length doesn't matter.

You are right about the 2-byte chars. Latin character set would also cause problems, but the issue of mixing cases (upper and lower) could be easily resolved by masking off the 5th bit (32) to convert to upper case (or oring with 32 to convert to lower case).

The ASCII character table assigns an integer to all characters:

```
@ = 64 = 01**0**00000   ...  
A = 65 = 01**0**00001   ...   a =  97 = 01**1**00001
B = 66 = 01**0**00010   ...   b =  98 = 01**1**00010 
.. 
Z = 90 = 01**0**11010   ...   z = 122 = 01**1**11010
```

Upper and lower case characters differ only on that particular bit and `'a' - 32 == 'A'` or the other way round: `'B' + 32 == 'b'` or `'B' | 32 == 'b'`, where `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Comment: thanks really good explanation. But can you elaborate little more about the case for lower and upper case.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as bit masking .Here checker is the bit mask.

The first expression `:if((checker&(1<<val))>0)` gets the bit and the second expression `checker|=(1<<val)` sets the bit.

The left shift operator raises the by 2^val.So you have something like 001000 (for 'd').

The & operator returns true whenever both the checker's ith bit and the new val(001000) are 1.So you know if that character was already covered or not.

The | operator simply sets the ith bit to 1 .So if at some instance checker was 010000, Now it become 011000.